# Make: Use cat to merge files with linefeed

Tags: shell, for-loop, makefile, gnu-make, cat

I'm writing a makefile for some personal documents written in Markdown and want to merge all files together in building time so I don't have to edit the Makefile every single time I add a new file. This is my code:

```
MERGE:
        @printf "Merging all files into one...\n"
        @cp .yaml tmp
        @for file in *.md;\
         do\
         cat $$file;\
         echo "";\
         done > tmp
        @mv tmp tmp.md
```

Alas, whenever I run it, `make` returns this and freezes:

```
Merging all files into one...
cat: 0: No such file or directory
```

I've read that I may be calling `cat` as file? But I'm using the correct `for` syntax and escaping `$` as `$$`.

What am I doing wrong, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the follwing loop:

```
for file in *.md; do
   cat "$file"
   echo ""
done >> tmp.md
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! Where can I find documentation about the difference between passing args with or without quotes?